# Can voltage be increased without coils?

Tags: transistors, coil

I have a $5 solar lamp.

I have recently repaired it. It has a 1.5V rechargeable battery, a small solar panel, a yellow LED, a power switch, a transistor, a diode and some resistors.

I am a little confused because I have tested the yellow LED and it begins to glow slightly at 1.9V, but the battery only has ~1.5V.

How can the LED glow at night?

Does the solar lamp increase the voltage?
How can that be without coils?

I am also thankful for an answer like "The solar lamp cannot increase the voltage".

Then it's my fault and I didn't look well at the circuit.

(By the way I have other solar lamps and they all have no coils. So I really wonder how this works.)

Comment: Post a picture of the circuit board.  Some inductors look like resistors.

Comment: Capacitive pumps are a thing, but that's probably not what is being used.

Comment: Here's an example of a solar light which has an **inductor** which looks like a **resistor**: https://dzrmo.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/garden-light/ Since the current is very small, this type of inductor (with a low saturation current, looking like a resistor) can be used.

Comment: Inductive converters are most common at higher powers. At low  power there are also capacitive and even diode based voltage multipliers. Post a picture of your board.